# Broadcasting 2 WEBRTC signals to multiple WEBRTC clients

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, webrtc, rtmp

I want to create an online classes type of site. I want the tutor to broadcast to all students and if a student has a question they can broadcast to ask the whole class. Meaning only a max of 2 people will be broadcasting. I would want to use webRTC but connecting like 30 people would give to much overhead. Is there a way of broadcasting 2 signals to 30 users using webRTC where the 30 remain dumb clients while using SOCKET IO for signalling?

Came across RTMP when doing my research and would like to ask if the tutor and the student (with the question) could "stream" their sessions to the other students. Where both can communicate with Webrtc after which streams are broadcasted to the others.

Can it be done ? Can it be done using REACT, SOCKET IO, WEBRTC and or RTMP ?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to send the stream to some users, then let those users retransmit to others. This can be done with [webrtc scalable broadcasting](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Scalable-Broadcast). There will be more latency the more users come in between though.

A more used solution in an [SFU](https://webrtcglossary.com/sfu/). With this solution the sender will only need to send once stream to the server and the server handles all the retransmission to the other users. So by having a more powerful server you can easily scale your application for more users. There are several ways to implement this:

- [Janus-gateway](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/)
- [Kurento](https://www.kurento.org/)
- [Mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org/)

[Here](https://github.com/Dirvann/mediasoup-sfu-webrtc-video-rooms) is a simple example project of how videoconferencing is implemented with mediasoup.